# Padding applied to #wrapper

Tags: css

Newbie question here. I have a #wrapper as my main container. Like so:

```
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 960px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

My question is: what is the actual width of the wrapper now? 960px or 1000px? Let's say I want to have a #header inside the #wrapper. What should the width of my #header be, assuming I want it to be the width of the #wrapper?

Answer (score 2):

The width of the wrapper in your example is now 1000px.  Padding is added to the width, wheras Margin is not.

If you put a header inside the wrapper, you would want it to be 1000px to stretch entirely from side to side, but that would be impossible because of the padding, so your header would still have to be 960px.

Heres a JSFiddle (Sorry, just discovered this today!)

http://jsfiddle.net/wGYfR/8/

Answer (score 1):

The outer width is 1000px and the inner width is 960px. So if you want to put inside the wrapper it should have width <= 960px

Comment: So if I want to have a white border inside the #wrapper while keeping the 960px width, then I should do this instead:

#wrapper {
margin: 0 auto:
padding: 0;
width: 960px;
height: 100px;
}

#header {
margin: 0 20px;
padding: 0;
width: 940px;
height: 10;
}

Correct?

Comment: Yes, I think this would work. But why don't you just try it yourself and check the result with firebug, [Firebug introduction](http://getfirebug.com/video/Intro2FB.htm) ?

Answer (score 1):

The wrapper is still 960px.  However, you have added padding of 20px on both sides meaning for 20px on both sides there will be only white space.  The usable area is now 920px.

You don't have to set the width of the header.  If you don't it will fill the whole wrapper element (minus the padding).  You header will end up being 920px.

I suggest [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) This will help you so much.  Seriously.

Comment: Sorry but this is not correct, the usable width would still be 960 and the total width would be 1000 (width + padding).

Comment: Modern browsers generally interpret things in the same way, it doesn't mean that how it works makes complete sense, but it is nonetheless how it works!

Answer (score 0):

The actual width would still be 1000px. You can set a background color on your #wrapper to see that the width will still be 1000px.

[CSS Box Model Illustration http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/3402/boxmodel.png](http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/3402/boxmodel.png)

Comment: I thought the illustration to be helpful, so I hosted it on imageshack and inserted it within the post. If you don't like the change you can rollback the revision.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to embed it!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chrome or Safari (or firebug with Firefox for that matter) you can easily check out the width of an element, and how padding and margin in affecting it.

[image: http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/5139/screenshot20110330at630.png]

Answer (score 0):

The width should be 960px, however only FireFox adds the padding to the width.
To fix this, put the following code on top (or at least above all div selectors) of your code:

```
DIV {   /*let Firefox stick to the web standard concerning padding*/
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```